# Use \forestset macro to automatically turn on math-mode in each node, and color the 2nd component of every couple?

Tags: math-mode, macros, color, forest, trees

I want to produce a binary tree, where at each node I will enter a couple (e.g. $(8,16)$ or $(S_2,M_2)$), and the second component is colored red.
How do I use the `\forestset` macro (from the *forest package*) to do that automatically, so that when I write a tree I can write in the node e.g. `{{S_2}{M_2}}}` (or similar) instead of `{$(S_2,{\color{red} M_2})$ }`?
In particular, how do I get the content of each node to be automatically in math mode, without having to write `$...$` every time?

Better yet if the macro also specifies that, **if** I enter 3 arguments, then the third is colored blue, so that I can write e.g. `{{S_2}{M_2}{A_2}}` (or similar) instead of `{$(S_2,{\red M_2},{\color{blue} A_2})$ }`

Answer (score 4):

To have a node typeset in math mode, use key `math content`, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [2^{42}, math content
    [A]
    [A, math content]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Actually, `math content` is just a wrapper for `content format`. It puts `\ensuremath` around the content when typesetting it. But it can be used to dress up the content (without changing it) in any way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  quote/.style={
    content format={``\forestoption{content}''}
  },
  bold/.style={
    content format={\noexpand\textbf{\forestoption{content}}}
  },      
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A
    [B, quote]
    [C, bold]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

To have *all* the nodes in a tree automatically typeset in math mode, use `math content` inside the spatial propagator `for tree`. `for tree` is actually a bit of a misnomer, as it actually applies the given options to all the nodes in a *sub*tree, but ahh well ... it is true to its name if it is used at the root node, or in the tree preamble, like below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={math content}
  [S_1
    [S_2]
    [S_3]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Making different things happen to different parts of the content is a bit more involved, but Forest comes equipped for the job. The `split` family of keys takes some text, splits it at a given separator, and applies (possibly different) keys to each part. I'll illustrate this in a moment, but let me first list the family members: `split` applies to the given text; `split option` takes the text from some (forest) option; and `split register` takes the text from some (forest) register. Below, we will use `split option`, and it will act on option `content`, where the node content (stuff between the brackets up to the first comma) is stored.

And now, without further ado, the solution to the OPs problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  1st/.style={content'={#1}},
  2nd/.style={content+'={,{\color{red}#1}}},
  rest/.style={content+'={,{\color{blue}#1}}},
  autocolored math/.style={
    delay={
      for tree={
        math content,
        split option={content}{;}{1st,2nd,rest},
        content={(##1)},
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} autocolored math
  [S_1;M_1
    [S_2;M_2]
    [S_3;M_3;A_3
      [S_4;M_4;A_4]
      [S_5;M_5;A_5;B_5]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The core of the `autocolored math` style is of course the invocation of `split option`. It takes the text from option `content` (the first argument), and splits it at occurrences of `;` (the second argument). So far, so good. What about the third argument, `1st,2nd,rest`?

The third argument lists some style names. The first style (`1st`) will get the first part of the content as its argument (`S_1`, `S_2`, etc.). The second style (`2nd`) will get the first part of the content as its argument (`M_1`, `M_2`, etc.). The third style (`rest`) will get ... but wait, what it there is no third argument? No problem: in such case (1 and 2 in the tree), `rest` is never invoked. And as the name `rest` implies, there may be more than three arguments, and the last style will be called for each extra argument (5 in the tree).  (By the way, the style names can obviously be anything.)

A word on `content` (see below `split option`) vs. `content'` (in the definition of `1st`). The `content` key is a bit special. `content=...` "autowraps" the value of the `content` option, i.e. `##1` in `content={(##1)}` refers to the current value of option `content` (and then puts parentheses around it). (The doubled `##` is there because we are within the definition of `autocolored math`.) `content'` behaves "normally", so in `1st/.style={content'={#1}}`, `#1` refers to the argument of `1st` (in our case, this will be the first part of the split expression).

`content+` appends the given text to the current value of the option. Well, in the above code, I have actually used the non-autowrapping version`content+'`.

Finally, note that I have put `math content` above `split option`, while one might have expected that it belongs after `content={(##1)}`. This was just to demostrate that it would work anywhere (within `for tree`). The point is that `math content` does not affect the value of option `content` at all. It rather determines (via `content format`) how this value is used.

Last but not least, why the `delay`? By default, the options of the parent are processed before the options of the children; this includes the setting content of the node by `[...]`. So `autocolored math`, which occurs at the root node (well, in the preamble, which is slightly different in principle ...), applies before the content of any node is set! If there was no `delay`, there would be nothing to split.